# justify-content in Explorer and Safari

Tags: css, internet-explorer, safari, flexbox

What am I doing wrong? In Chrome, Firefox, Opera it is cool but not in Safari/Explorer.

Parent is in the bottom right corner, `child1` over parent (vertical centered with parent). Parent may have a different size and the child must be still over it.

[image: example image]

```css
.cotainer{
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   margin: 10px;
}


.parent {
   width: 80px;
   height:80px;
   min-width: 80px;
   min-height:80px;
   background-color:#8BBF46;
   border-radius:50%;
   bottom: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   margin: 15px;
   order: 1;
   order: -webkit-1;
   order: -moz-1;
   order: -ms-1;
   order: -webkit-1;
}

.child1{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 100%;
}

.child2{
   font-size: 16px;
   color: #222;
   padding: 0.4em;
   display: block;

}

.child2:hover{
   color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style-okrojone.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="cotainer">
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child1"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbnsI.jpg" alt="grafika-dodatkowa"></div>
            <i class="child2">parent</i>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that your `parent` container is a flexbox, but your `child1` uses `position: absolute`. You should not use absolute positioning for elements in a flexbox, as this is [not offically supported](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items).

So it looks like chrome is able to render it the "correct" way, but some other browser may not be. The best would be to change your layout, so that you don't use a flexbox and an absolute position anymore.

Answer (score 0):

give your img these additional styles

```
margin-left: -306px; /* has to be half of the image width */
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

and your .child1 these additional styles

```
width: 100%;
left: 0;
```

hope this works for you...